# laravel datepicker: how to load jquery icon

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datepicker

I am new to laravel, I am trying to add a datepicker on the page,

This is my mark up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<<div style="display:table-cell;width:50%">
     <input class="date_picker_icon" name="ddl_date"></input>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my script part:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"   </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<script>

        $( function() {
        $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
        });
    } );
        formNextReviewDate();
        function formNextReviewDate(){
            let field = $("[name='ddl_date']");
            field.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' ,
            });


        field.datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
        
    }
</script>
</html>
```

The result on the page is shown below:
[image]

The problem is that there is blank space rather than icon when I want to change the month, and I want to add 'dd/mm/yy' in the box before choosing a date. Can you please help me to firgure it out? Many THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to add 'dd/mm/yy' in the box before choosing a date." - To achieve this you could use placeholder, like this:

```
<div style="display:table-cell;width:50%">
    <input class="date_picker_icon" name="ddl_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy"></input>
</div>
```

To display the jQuery UI icons, you must include a jQuery UI theme. If you haven't done this, include a link to the jQuery UI theme in the  section of your HTML document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Also ensure you're loading jQuery and jQuery UI in the correct order before your script. Here's an example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Also you are initializing datepicker twice, which is not necessary:

```
$(function() {
    formNextReviewDate();

    function formNextReviewDate(){
        let field = $("[name='ddl_date']");
        field.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: really thanks for your detailed answer. I resolved the placeholder problem. Can I ask  how I can load the jQuery and jQuery UI correctly? I am not sure how to find the correct source. THX!

Comment: and I also updated my code sample, please have a check

Comment: Use urls which I have provided.

Comment: I tried to add the script src code before the script, but the it did not work

Comment: @RA.IBOY Did you achieve it ?

Comment: ah I didn't, I am trying to use flatpickr but I got a problem with installing hhhh.